# Filter existing table to another table without adding measures or column on existing table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create a table based on input table.
Input table is:

[image: Input table]

The new table filters the input table to show the last entry of every day.

I have tried working with measure but sometimes cant tell if it is working right until I graph it in pivot tables which is not so bad but sometimes just doesn't show me what I need to see exactly.
I have tried this measure:

```
History_Daily Efficiency = 
VAR LastDailyEfficiency = 
    GENERATE(
        VALUES ('Table_Full'[Cell]),
        CALCULATETABLE (
            TOPN (
                1,
                GROUPBY (
                    'Table_Full',
                    'Table_Full'[Date],
                    'Table_Full'[Time],
                    'Table_Full'[Efficiency]
                ),
                'Table_Full'[Date], DESC,
                'Table_Full'[Time], DESC,
                'Table_Full'[Efficiency], ASC
            )
        )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGE('Table_Full'[Efficiency]),
        TREATAS( LastDailyEfficiency, 'Table_Full'[Cell], 'Table_Full'[Date], 'Table_Full'[Time], 'Table_Full'[Efficiency]),
        'Table_Full'[Efficiency] < 80
    )
```

But I got this:
[image: wrong result]

I would like to see this as the output:
[image: output table = input table minus the blacked out lines]

Comment: Is the problem that the matrix visual isn't displaying [Job/Part Number]? If so, you need to add that field to the matrix. This question is a bit difficult to understand, because the measure is clearly referring to different data than you're showing us.

Comment: No, that is not the problem.
I created multiple measures but all on the same structure as the one I showed above so one measure for efficiency one for part count one for sales etc...The pictures I showed may have showed a different measure but the idea is the same... In other words, you can replace the above [efficiency] measure with [part count] which is available in the above input table... whether it is [job/part number] or efficiency or sales or cost or whatever, I want the new table to filter all rows except for one at the end of each day.. Is that too hard or impossible?

Comment: I was able to create a table that is filtering the input but it is always showing the very last date.. I need to show the last of every day not just the last day
Table_Daily = UNION(
TOPN(1,DISTINCT('csl_1new sill-fender cell1 status'),'csl_1new sill-fender cell1 status'[DateTime],),
TOPN(1,DISTINCT('csl_1new sill-fender cell2 status'),'csl_1new sill-fender cell2 status'[DateTime],),

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table:

```
LastDayCount = GROUPBY(Table_Full;Table_Full[lob/Part Number];Table_Full[Date];"LastDate";MAXX(CURRENTGROUP(); Table_Full[DateTime]))
```

This will create a table with the last DateTime of the day.

Next we add a column giving us the max of that particular last datetime of the day. I noticed that you have more the same entries, the logic below takes the max part count at the end of the day when more than one entry.

```
Count = 
CALCULATE(MAX(Table_Full[Part Count]);
    FILTER(Table_Full;LastDayCount[Table_Full_lob/Part Number] = Table_Full[lob/Part Number] 
    && LastDayCount[LastDate] = Table_Full[DateTime]))
```

End result:
[image]